Memory leak and gopacket/pcap
I have a memory leak in my application which use gopacket/pcap : memory consumption increases continuously when the application receives network traffic.
My code :
src := gopacket.NewPacketSource(p.parent.pcapHandle, layers.LayerTypeEthernet)
in := src.Packets()
for {
    select {
    case err = <-tg.IsClosingEvent():
        return err
    case packet := <-in:
        fmt.Print(packet)
    }
}

Prototype of IsClosingEvent : func (h *ThreadGroup) IsClosingEvent() <-chan error {
During my application works, tg.IsClosingEvent() is never used : it is to manage a application close event. If I comment case of tg.IsClosingEvent(), the problem doesn't appear.
When I use this code, I don't have problem :
    src := gopacket.NewPacketSource(p.parent.pcapHandle, layers.LayerTypeEthernet)
    in := src.Packets()
    stopCh := make(chan error)
    for {
        select {
        case err = <-stopCh:
            return err

        case packet := <-in:
            fmt.Print(packet)
            if packet.String() == "a" {
                stopCh <- errors.New("a")
            }
        }
    }

I don't understand, it seems to be the same thing.
Where is the problem ?
For information pcapHandle is :
handle, err := pcap.OpenLive(interfaceName, 65536, true, pcap.BlockForever)

IsClosingEvent function :
func (h *ThreadGroup) IsClosingEvent() <-chan error {
    ch := make(chan error, 1)
    go func() {
        <-h.ctx.Done()
        ch <- h.msgClosed()
    }()
    return ch
}
func (h *ThreadGroup) msgClosed() error {
    return errors.New("Thread Group \"" + h.name + "\" is Closed")
}


It's not clear what tg is.

tg is the library that manages the closing of my application : tg.IsClosingEvent() returns a channel to indicate receipt of the closing message. This channel isn't set in normal operation : That's why I don't understand why the behaviour is different between my two examples.

Every time you call ThreadGroup.IsClosingEvent(), it creates a new channel. What you want to do is call that func once, store the channel in a variable and use case err = <- yourVar to check if you should exit the loop. Btw did you write this "tg library" yourself? Google can't find it for me.
